# Jquery FadeIn FadeOut keeps repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Here's my code:

```
$('.class').fadeOut(function(){
    $('#image').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut(); 
});
```

It fades in, waits one second and then fades out. But then it repeats.

**EDIT 1:** It also does it four times only.

**EDIT 2:** `.class` applies to four elements.

Comment: can you post the html? the div and the image, wherever they are in your markup, without chaning anything.

Comment: When is this code run?  On ready, onclick, etc.

Comment: why not use the when done function? => $(".elements").fadeOut();

$.when( $(".elements") ).done(function( elements ) {
    // all elements faded out
});

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.done/ also search for .done on http://blog.jquery.com/  think you make some mistakes, #image is also a div? so then everytime you fadeout div#image the function for div.fadeout ill be triggered

Comment: I have edit a better EDIT which should make more sense now.

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

```
$('option').fadeOut().last().queue(function(){
   //here fade in and out the image
}
```

Comment: Please give some explanation with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

If the "#image" id is on a div element, you are firing the parent event from the child event causing recursion(loop). Give the div(s) their own id or class.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have 4 div elements in your page, for each div element you tell to  jquery to "fadeIn,wait 1s and fadeout" this element:"$('#image')", so jquery do it as you request it.

"But I want the #image to appear only after the four class elements have faded out."

```
var counter=0;
$('.class').fadeOut(function(){
    ++counter;
    if(counter==4) $('#image').fadeIn().delay(1000).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If there are four `class` element, your `$('.class').fadeOut()` function will fire four times (see http://jsfiddle.net/DrZcj/2/). You can separate the two functions to make sure your `#image` function is only called once.

Maybe something like: http://jsfiddle.net/DrZcj/3/

EDIT:

Is this what you're looking for: http://jsfiddle.net/DrZcj/4/

Comment: But I want the #image to appear only after the four class elements have faded out.

Comment: In the updated answer, the four class elements should fade out, then the `#image` element appears. Is that what you want to happen?

Answer (score 0):

If all other answers didn't solve your issue, you need to make sure your js file is not referenced twice or you the event attached twice.
Had the same issue before and found that I had the file referenced twice in my page.